# WiX: Replace sub directory on upgrade

Tags: wix

I'm using WiX to install some program v1.0 which brings its own JRE 8.x, located in a sub directory `jre/`. Now I'm upgrading my program to version 1.1, which is based on an 11.x JRE. My `MajorUpgrade` is

```
<MajorUpgrade Schedule="afterInstallExecute" DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed."/>
```

> **Update 1:** I'd like to keep `afterInstallExecute` because there are a
>   couple of files I'd like to keep.

***So what's the WiX way to replace that/any sub directory completely?***

- I tried to just replace JRE 8 with JRE 11. Turns out this leaves existing files in place, especially `jre/lib/ext/`. But as updating a JRE from below v9 to v9+ [requires that folder **not** to exist](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/migrate/toc.htm#JSMIG-GUID-2C896CA8-927C-4381-A737-B1D81D964B7B), the JVM refuses to start after the upgrade
- so I tried to mark all files within the `jre/`-sub dir with `RemoveFile ... On='install'` ([source](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Using-wix-how-to-always-overwrite-a-file-tp6904118p6904975.html)), hoping installing the new files would remove the old files, but that did not work
- finally instead reusing `jre/` I put all my JRE 8 files in sub directory `jre-8u181/` and JRE 11 files in `jre-11.0.2_7/`, hoping WiX recognizes "oh, I do not need sub dir `jre-8u181/` any longer, so I can delete it". Doesn't work either.

> **Update 2:** The JRE folder is included via
>
> ```
> <Directory Id='foo_jre_32' Name='jre'>
>   <?include jre32.wxi ?>
> </Directory>
> ```
>
> with jre32.wxi being a rather long, auto-generated list like
>
> ```
> <Include>
>   <Component Id='_6387aee1c48be620fded05f509eb61ef' Guid='*'>
>     <File Id='_e566fc2d9d74ea7a1249736056b2a2e4' Source='foo\jre\THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME.txt' Name='THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME.txt' DiskId='1' />
>   </Component>
>   <Component Id='_0dcaf4ce39ea5a8ab63704e6e8e23514' Guid='*'>
>     <File Id='_9e93e8a3fced0b6549171fc677dad65c' Source='foo\jre\README.txt' Name='README.txt' DiskId='1' />
>   </Component>
>   <Component Id='_2fa36d02341dba40d7dd8dabc21aa506' Guid='*'>
>     <File Id='_3654927acd82cae7b37fb9b7c92a6615' Source='foo\jre\release' Name='release' DiskId='1' />
>   </Component>
>     <Directory Id='_9b3d18d11d414dfb14909186a8ebb330' Name='lib'>
>       <!-- ... -->
> ```

Comment: Windows Installer installs/removes Components. A directory cannot be a component. Usually, each file is an individual component. Windows Installer selects which component to install/remove by which Features of all Products that the component is a member of are selected for install/removal/retention. So, how have you organized this for the already released installer version?

Comment: Exactly that way, see Update 2: As a list of components (and directories, within one large include)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found it, thanks to @tom-blodget: I include the JRE folder as a set of `Directory` and `Component`/`File`. The `File` have a `Guid`, which is fixed (I need them to be reproducible across our build systems to allow references to them). I didn't update them for the new JRE folder m( Now I do, plus I install the JRE folders (old and new one) to different target folders (option #3 in my initial question). Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Change attribute to `Schedule="afterInstallValidate"` (or remove the attribute, because this is the default).

This causes Windows Installer to completely remove the existing version before installing the new version of the product. You can now remove the folder simply by omitting it from your new version.

This scheduling of Major Upgrade is what I recommend in general. It gives you the least headaches because the new version installation will always start "fresh", without remains of the old version (unless there are user-modified files). Sure this will be somewhat slower than `Schedule="afterInstallExecute"`, but a correct installation is more important than an installation that is 2 seconds faster.

See also documentation of [MajorUpgrade element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/majorupgrade.html).

Comment: Thanks for the tipp. I'd rather keep it as `afterInstallValidate` (see Update 1) because there are several files I'd like to keep, which get deleted `on="Uninstall" – seems this attribute is triggered even on update, and allows only `Install`, `Uninstall` or `both`, so I cannot skip the deletion with some more sophisticated logic. However, this is a valid fallback in case there's no other solution, so thanks again!